# Proving/refuting that $ \big\{\sqrt{2}\cos\big((\pi/2+\pi n)x\big)\big\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}}$ is an $L^2[0,1]$ basis

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

I'm trying to prove that $ \big\{\sqrt{2}\cos\big((\pi/2+\pi n)x\big)\big\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}}$ is an orthonormal basis for $L^2[0,1]$.

I thought of using the fact that $ \big\{\sqrt{2}\cos(\pi nx)\big\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}}$ is an orthonormal basis for $L^2[0,1]$ by using the representation $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\alpha_n \cos(\pi nx)$ to transition to the new basis and show that, it too, can yield $f(x)$, but there doesn't seem to be a trigonometric identity that helps accomplish this.

It seems redundant to prove from scratch that $ \big\{\sqrt{2}\cos\big((\pi/2+\pi n)x\big)\big\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}}$ is a basis for $L^2[0,1]$ given that there's one very similar. In any case, doing this from scratch, I have been able to show that this is an orthonormal system, but couldn't complete the proof to show it is a basis.

I've also been unsuccessful in trying to refute that it is a basis.

Any ideas either way?

A related post that may be helpful (but didn't help me) [is this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1800012/eigenfunctions-of-an-integral-operator).

Comment: If $\sqrt{2} \cos((\pi/2+\pi n)x)$ was a basis, then you should be able to expand $\cos(\pi x/2)$ on $(0,4)$. But $$\langle \cos(\pi x/2) , \cos((\pi/2+\pi n)x) \rangle=0 \,. $$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I guess the OP includes $n=0$ into $\mathbb{N}.$ Otherwise standard cosines do not form a basis as a constant functions are orthogonal to the truncated system.

Comment: Then pick $\sin(\pi x/2)$ instead.

Comment: OP deals with even functions. The same problem would be with standard cosines. The question should be re edited

Comment: So the question really is whether $\cos((\pi/2+\pi n)x)$ is a basis for even functions? I don't think that is clear. Since $\sin (\pi n x)$ is a basis on $(0,1)$ and not just odd functions (for odd functions on $(-1,1)$). He doesn't specify an interval.

Comment: I think so. Otherwise it is trivial as the standard consines do not form a basis.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc is right. Apologies for causing the confusion - I have now updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f:(0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $\frac{e^{i\pi x/2}}{2} g(x)$ its even extension on $(-1,1)$. Then $g(x)$ is some complex function on $(-1,1)$ which can be expanded as $$g(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n e^{i\pi n x} \,.$$
The eveness requires $$\frac{e^{-i\pi x/2}}{2} \, g(-x) = \frac{e^{i\pi x/2}}{2} \, g(x)$$
which after some algebra gives $$c_n = c_{-n-1} \quad n=0,1,2,...\,.$$
Finally $$\frac{e^{i\pi x/2}}{2} \, g(x)= \frac12 \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n e^{i\pi x(n+1/2)}= \frac12 \left( \sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \right) c_n e^{i\pi x(n+1/2)} \\
=\frac12 \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_{-n-1} e^{-i\pi x(n+1/2)} + \frac12 \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n e^{i\pi x(n+1/2)} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n \cos(\pi x (n+1/2)) \, .$$

Comment: Nice solution !